# make and shell redirection based on exit status

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, redirect

I have a make rule which generates a dependencies file for a list of sources. This is the rule:

```
.depend: $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -MM $^ | sed 's-^\(.*\):-$(OBJDIR)\/\1:-'> .depend
```

What I want is: If gcc fails for any file in $(SRC) then .depend should not be created. Currently, if gcc fails on a source file I will get an incomplete .depend which will not be regenerated after I fix the issue. What can I do? I'd like to avoid having a .depend file for each source file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
.dependlist: $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -MM $^ > $@

.depends: .dependlist
    sed 's-^\(.*\):-$(OBJDIR)\/\1:-' $< > $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.DELETE_ON_ERROR`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors) target:

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
.depend: $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -MM $^ | sed 's-^\(.*\):-$(OBJDIR)\/\1:-'> .depend
```

From [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets):

> If `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` is mentioned as a target anywhere in the makefile, then make will delete the target of a rule if it has changed and its recipe exits with a nonzero exit status, just as it does when it receives a signal.

Comment: This won't work because sed will return 0 as exit status anyway fooling make